# Two function inside one function one as props and one as function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating a common component for calendar. I need to call two function inside one function like:-

```
onDateChange = {()=>{ props.onDateChange,setShowCal()}}
```

so `setShowCal()` can close the calendar once selected and `props.onDateChange` give selected date in parent component.

but only `setShowCal()` is working and `props.onDateChange` is not working.

Full code of common component :-

```
export const PrimaryCalendar = (props)=>{
const [showCal, setShowCal] = React.useState(false);
const mindate = new Date();
const showCalendar = ()=>{
    setShowCal(!showCal)
}
return(
    <View>
    {(showCal) ? 
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <CalendarPicker
        selectedDayColor="#079B2B"
        minDate = {mindate}
        startFromMonday={true}
        allowRangeSelection={true}
        todayBackgroundColor="#79AE08"
        previousTitle="Previous"
          nextTitle="Next"
        onDateChange = {()=>{ props.onDateChange,setShowCal()}}
        />
        </View>
    :
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.calendarInputContainer} onPress={()=>showCalendar()}>
        <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:25}}>{props.title}</Text>
        <Icon name="calendar" size={30} color={'white'}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    }
        </View>
)
```

}

How I can implement it?
Thanks!!!

Comment: You are not calling props.onDateChange. Change your code like onDateChange = {()=>{ props.onDateChange(); setShowCal()}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const PrimaryCalendar = (props)=>{
const [showCal, setShowCal] = React.useState(false);
const mindate = new Date();
const showCalendar = ()=>{
    setShowCal(!showCal)
}
const handleOnDateChange = () =>{
    props.onDateChange()
    setShowCal()
}
return(
    <View>
    {(showCal) ? 
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <CalendarPicker
        selectedDayColor="#079B2B"
        minDate = {mindate}
        startFromMonday={true}
        allowRangeSelection={true}
        todayBackgroundColor="#79AE08"
        previousTitle="Previous"
          nextTitle="Next"
        onDateChange = { handleOnDateChange }
        />
        </View>
    :
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.calendarInputContainer} onPress={()=>showCalendar()}>
        <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:25}}>{props.title}</Text>
        <Icon name="calendar" size={30} color={'white'}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    }
        </View>
)
```

Make your `onChange` callback execute a function called `handleTextAreaChange` which then executes your `props.onDateChange()` and `setShowCal()`

Your mistake is `onDateChange = {()=>{ props.onDateChange,setShowCal()}}`

When declaring `() => { }` the stuff inside the curly brackets is a code block, which means comma separating your function calls is wrong.

Here is an example of how it's done

```
onChange={ () => {
            functionCall1()
            functionCall2()
          } }
```